# RPM lists missing dependencies that it contains

Tags: centos7, rpm

I am attempting to build the CORBA omniORB packages on CentOS 7.

I manage to build the RPM, but when I go to install it, it lists failed dependencies that are part of the RPM itself!

I am hoping someone might be able to suggest what to check!

```
$ sudo rpm -i omniORB-4.2.2-1.x86_64.rpm 
error: Failed dependencies:
    libCOS4.so.2()(64bit) is needed by omniORB-4.2.2-1.x86_64
    libCOSDynamic4.so.2()(64bit) is needed by omniORB-4.2.2-1.x86_64
    libomniCodeSets4.so.2()(64bit) is needed by omniORB-4.2.2-1.x86_64
    libomniConnectionMgmt4.so.2()(64bit) is needed by omniORB-4.2.2-1.x86_64
    libomniDynamic4.so.2()(64bit) is needed by omniORB-4.2.2-1.x86_64
    libomniORB4.so.2()(64bit) is needed by omniORB-4.2.2-1.x86_64
    libomniZIOP4.so.2()(64bit) is needed by omniORB-4.2.2-1.x86_64
    libomniZIOPDynamic4.so.2()(64bit) is needed by omniORB-4.2.2-1.x86_64
    libomnithread.so.4()(64bit) is needed by omniORB-4.2.2-1.x86_64

$ rpm -qpl omniORB-4.2.2-1.x86_64.rpm | grep -e "lib.*so"
/opt/omniORB-4.2.2/lib/libCOS4.so
/opt/omniORB-4.2.2/lib/libCOS4.so.2
/opt/omniORB-4.2.2/lib/libCOS4.so.2.2
/opt/omniORB-4.2.2/lib/libCOSDynamic4.so
/opt/omniORB-4.2.2/lib/libCOSDynamic4.so.2
/opt/omniORB-4.2.2/lib/libCOSDynamic4.so.2.2
/opt/omniORB-4.2.2/lib/libomniCodeSets4.so
/opt/omniORB-4.2.2/lib/libomniCodeSets4.so.2
/opt/omniORB-4.2.2/lib/libomniCodeSets4.so.2.2
/opt/omniORB-4.2.2/lib/libomniConnectionMgmt4.so
/opt/omniORB-4.2.2/lib/libomniConnectionMgmt4.so.2
/opt/omniORB-4.2.2/lib/libomniConnectionMgmt4.so.2.2
/opt/omniORB-4.2.2/lib/libomniDynamic4.so
/opt/omniORB-4.2.2/lib/libomniDynamic4.so.2
/opt/omniORB-4.2.2/lib/libomniDynamic4.so.2.2
/opt/omniORB-4.2.2/lib/libomniORB4.so
/opt/omniORB-4.2.2/lib/libomniORB4.so.2
/opt/omniORB-4.2.2/lib/libomniORB4.so.2.2
/opt/omniORB-4.2.2/lib/libomniZIOP4.so
/opt/omniORB-4.2.2/lib/libomniZIOP4.so.2
/opt/omniORB-4.2.2/lib/libomniZIOP4.so.2.2
/opt/omniORB-4.2.2/lib/libomniZIOPDynamic4.so
/opt/omniORB-4.2.2/lib/libomniZIOPDynamic4.so.2
/opt/omniORB-4.2.2/lib/libomniZIOPDynamic4.so.2.2
/opt/omniORB-4.2.2/lib/libomnithread.so
/opt/omniORB-4.2.2/lib/libomnithread.so.4
/opt/omniORB-4.2.2/lib/libomnithread.so.4.0
/opt/omniORB-4.2.2/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/_omniidlmodule.so
/opt/omniORB-4.2.2/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/_omniidlmodule.so.4
/opt/omniORB-4.2.2/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/_omniidlmodule.so.4.2
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Show your `.spec` file. I think you are missing the `findprovides` check by done `rpm` macros during build.

Comment: I eventually just gave up and am using the OS provided packages.